# Looing values in one dataframe based on conditions from rows in another

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add column to df1 that looks up value from df2 using conditions based on rows from df1.

For example:

df1

```
Name  Date     Score   Country
John  1st Jan   5        US
John  2nd Jan   6        US
Phil  1st Jan   4        Canada
Phil  2nd Jan   8        Canada
Phil  3rd Jan   7        Canada
```

I would like to have formula that looks up  value of another column in df2  if Name =John, Date is > 1st of Jan , and country is = US. 
The same for all other rows.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ["Name","Date","Score","Country"]
data=[
    ["John","1st Jan","5","US"],
    ["John","2nd Jan","6","US"],
    ["Phil","1st Jan","4","Canada"],
    ["Phil","2nd Jan","8","Canada"],
    ["Phil","3rd Jan","7","Canada"]
]

columns2 = ["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"]
data2 = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4] ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = columns2)
print(df)
print(df2)

df.loc[(df['Name'] == "John")   & 
       (df['Date'] == "1st Jan")&
       (df['Score'] == "5")     &
       (df['Country'] == "US"), 'New'] = df2["Col1"]

name = "Phil"
date = "1st Jan"
score = "4"
country = "Canada"
df.loc[(df['Name'] == name)   & 
       (df['Date'] == date)   &
       (df['Score'] == score) &
       (df['Country'] == country), 'New'] = df2["Col2"]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Name     Date Score Country
0  John  1st Jan     5      US
1  John  2nd Jan     6      US
2  Phil  1st Jan     4  Canada
3  Phil  2nd Jan     8  Canada
4  Phil  3rd Jan     7  Canada
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     1     2     3     4
1     1     2     3     4
2     1     2     3     4
3     1     2     3     4
Name     Date Score Country  New
0  John  1st Jan     5      US  1.0
1  John  2nd Jan     6      US  NaN
2  Phil  1st Jan     4  Canada  2.0
3  Phil  2nd Jan     8  Canada  NaN
4  Phil  3rd Jan     7  Canada  NaN
```

**EDIT**

You can make this more automated, by using a function with `df.apply()` and a lambda calling the function.

```
def lambdafunc(row):
    name = row[0]
    date = row[1]
    score = row[2]
    country = row[3]
    df.loc[(df['Name'] == name)   & 
           (df['Date'] == date)   &
           (df['Score'] == score) &
           (df['Country'] == country), 'New'] = df2.loc[df2['Col1'] == name, 'Col4']


df.apply(lambda x: lambdafunc(x), axis = 1)

print(df)
```

Comment: Can this be done more automatically? I don't want to input new name ,score, country etc. every time just take the input of conditions from df rows and repeat the process for all rows?

Comment: Sure. You'll notice the second time I did the selection, I used variables. So, one way would be to use `df.iterrows()` to go through each line, set those variables, and then do the selection. You cold also create a function, and use the `df.apply()` with a lambda to call the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just 2 things, can I make the condition not "==" but ">"? Also If in conditions I would like to use row that's above current , would offset work?

Comment: You should be able to use greater-than/lesser-than. What error do you get? The issue may be that the data may not actually an int/datetime, but a string. You should verify/convert it.